# Local minima or maxima of conditional function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

How do I find the local minimum/maximum of this function?

$f:{R-2}\to{R}$

$f(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}e^{\left|x\right|}$

I wrote it like this
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{1}{x-2}e^x & x \ge 0 \\
\frac{1}{x-2}e^{-x} & x<0
\end{array}\right.$$

I differentiated the two parts of the function and equalized them to 0. I get $x=3$ and $x=1$ as points where my derivatives are 0. But as I see it my function is decreasing from $-\infty$ to 1 and then it starts increasing to $\infty$ . I think I'm having a problem with my domain.

I'm really at a loss here, since I can't find any examples of finding local minimum/maximum for these types of functions. What are these functions called in English, conditional functions?

Comment: I believe they are called Piecewise functions. It might be helpful to ask google to graph your function, or ask some other website capable of doing it, i.e. https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/PlottingAndGraphics.html.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried. But being a Piecewise function, how do I tell google/wolfram to graph it? It should be composed of two functions I guess, each with a set interval.

Comment: For example, [like this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[Exp[Abs[x]]+%2F+%28x-2%29%2C+{x%2C+-5%2C+5}]). The derivative isn't $0$ for $x = 1$.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to plot the function and I see my mistake now. $x=1$ isn't a solution that's in the domain for my second sub-function, where $x<0$, thus meaning I only have the $x=3$ point which should be a  local minimum I think.

Comment: I have an issue though, when I try to do the sign table so that I know whether $x=3$ is a minimum or a maximum, I see that my function is $-1/2$ for $x=0, -e$ for $x=1$ and for $x=2.5$ the function is positive again.

Comment: $f$ has  singularity at $2$. Checking $x \le 2$ makes no sense. Check the function at $x = 2.5$ and $x=4$, or better the derivative at those points.

Comment: Yeah, figured it out in the end. It's much more easier if you have the plot as well. $x=3$ is the local minima of the function. Thanks for all the help everyone!